# SharePoint ECMAScript for Mobile devices

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to execute some javascript code (SharePoint ECMA script model) to access SP data on mobile devices. However, the following code fails.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
 clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
       Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  
  });

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
  alert('Title: ' + this.oWebsite.get_title() + ' Decription: ' + this.oWebsite.get_description()); }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); }
```

Even, this code also fails on desktop browsers. Any idea?

Comment: Please reformat the question. Use Code Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

"Document ready" won't work. Instead call the SharePoint 2010 method `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`.  This must be added as the very first line of code after the script tag.  It will call your method when the SP Object is successfully loaded.  This resolves your issue on desktop browsers, I assume it will work for your mobile solution too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { 
    YourFunction()
},"sp.js");
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm this answer works on mobile (Android and iPhone)?